# Inserting records having a one-to-many relationship in Oracle 11gXE using SQL

Tags: java, sql, oracle, hibernate

I have a legacy schema in `Oracle 11g XE`. It has 2 tables (BANK and BANK BRANCH having a `one-to-many relationship`).

A simple structure of the BANK table :

```
BANK_CODE (VARCHAR2), BANK_NAME (VARCHAR2), MAIN_BANK_ADD (VARCHAR2) and
```

BANK_BRANCH table :

```
BANK_CODE (VARCHAR2), BRANCH_NAME (VARCHAR2), BRANCH_ADD (VARCHAR2)
```

So, in the table BANK_BRANCH the column BANK_CODE is a `foreign key` to the table BANK.

I plan to normalise all the tables in the schema, so that they all have an `id`. I have used `Hibernate` and mapped each record of these tables, and generated automatically the ids with a `sequence generator`. So, now I have new tables with the surrogate keys as required.

It was very cumbersome as there are a lot of records.

My question is How can I do this using SQL (or PL/SQL). I'm not too familiar with this language. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this just by two update statements (if BANK_CODE is unique for table BANK), for example with this script:

```
ALTER TABLE BANK ADD ID NUMBER;
ALTER TABLE BANK_BRANCH ADD BANK_ID NUMBER;

CREATE SEQUENCE BANK_SEQ;

UPDATE BANK
SET ID = BANK_SEQ.NEXTVAL;

UPDATE BANK_BRANCH t1
SET BANK_ID = (SELECT ID FROM BANK t2 WHERE t1.bank_code = t2.bank_code);

ALTER TABLE BANK ADD CONSTRAINT BANK_ID_UK UNIQUE (ID);

ALTER TABLE BANK_BRANCH ADD CONSTRAINT BANK_BRANCH_BANK_ID_FK FOREIGN KEY (BANK_ID) REFERENCES BANK(ID);
```